# Are there any risks of having none or few systems controlled by pirates?

Tags: space-rangers-hd

I've learned that taking a system over by pirates requires destroying military bases, ranger centers, business centers and science bases, which is bad for system protection from dominators. But are there any downsides to having no or very few systems controlled by pirates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few minor things.

- Pirate sectors are a safe haven for you to escape to if you are despised by other races.
- There are some pirate only equipment that you can buy from pirate sectors.
- There is a cheevo for a pirate victory.

Other than that, there is not benefit from having a large pirate population since it means there will be much fewer useful stations.